# Drupal doesn't send email to reset password

Tags: users

While having difficulty logging, I reset my password but the page stays and does no form action.

After I changed my password in the mysql database, I went to log in and the page does nothing even when I hit submit. Is there something wrong with my installation?

Comment: We need more data. Mails sent should be registered in watchdog. Are they? Are there any PHP errors in error.log? *"page does nothing even when I hit submit"* - what's in your browser's debug console? @GisleHannemyr is right, **something** is wrong, but you gave us no chance to guess what.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr @Molot - the OP gave a [URL](http://cie.austin.utexas.edu/uex-cm/user/login) in a comment on an answer that has since been deleted. It's pretty clear what was going on (all of the forms we're missing the wrapping `<form>` tags). It looks like OP was able to fix it too. @billpixby, can you edit your question to reflect what the real problem was (missing form tags) and post what your resolution was? I'd be interested to know what was causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick peek at your code (at http://cie.austin.utexas.edu/uex-cm/user/password) it looks like something is overriding the default HTML output for your forms. You're missing the `<form>` tags and the associated `action` and `method` attributes.

If you're looking for a quick fix (just to login one time) you can use Chrome Inspector or Firebug or similar to add the `form` tags around your form elements:

```
<form action="/uex-cm/user/login" method="post" id="user-login" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  // Your existing form elements
</form>
```

But ultimately, you'll need to figure out what is stripping the `<form>` tags from your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I was able to login stripping out the old theme. Where is the user page being generated so I can fix this?

Comment: It's almost impossible for us to guess what is overriding your forms (note that it's not just the login form - the password reset form has the same problem). If you switch themes and the problem goes away (likely), that would indicate that it's something in your template.php or some other theme file. If not, it could be in any custom or hacked contrib module. There's really no way for use to guess though, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Chrome DevTools to see if there is any kind of errors related to this, and use the "Network" tab to see if the request is triggered when you hit submit button.

Another thing to check is the logs, check the Apache error log.

You can also check the drupal log:

- If you have enabled the dblog module, check the watchog table to see if you can find an error related to this problem.
- If you have enabled the syslog module, check the syslog to see if you can find the problem.

If you have drush installed on the server, run:

```
drush core-requirements
```

to see if there is something that may be wrong in your Drupal installation.